# sql server select value depend by date

Tags: sql, date, join

I have 2 tables :

1. documents

   ```
   (docId | date | value | currencyid | currencyRate | netvalue )
   1 | 2017/07/30 | 777 | EUR | 4.55 | 150.66
   2 | 2017/07/30 | 456 | EUR | 4.55 | 100.00
   3 | 2017/07/29 | 440 | RON | 1.00 | 440.00
   4 | 2017/07/28 | 999 | RON | 1.00 | 999.00
   ```
2. currencyrates

   ```
   (only for currencyid = EUR)
   (date | currencyRate)
   2017/07/30 | 4.55
   2017/07/29 | 4.53
   2017/07/28 | 4.48
   ```

I need to extract by month, the total sum in euro for all documents. My problem is when I try to convert the local value (RON) from documents.value in EURO.

Example 1 in documents : when currencyid = EUR, netvalue is automaticaly calculated from value/currencyRate (in documents) and only what I need there is to extract documents.netvalue

the problem is :

Example 2 in documents : when currencyid = RON, netvalue is represented in RON and i need to convert it in EURO with the value at facturated date (not present date). So, I need to extract the currencyRate from currencyrates table for each date and use it in a CASE to divide value (in RON) at it.

and my query :

```
SELECT 
     p.name Client, year(d.date) AS Year, month(d.date) AS Month, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),d.CurrencyNetValue) CurrencyNetValue, d.CurrencyId, 
     CASE 
        WHEN d.CurrencyId = 1 THEN d.CurrencyNetValue/(select top 1(c.CurrencyRate) from CurrencyRates c inner join documents d on d.date=c.date where c.CurrencyId=2)
        WHEN d.CurrencyId = 2 THEN d.CurrencyNetValue
     END 
     AS EuroNetValue
     FROM documents d
     inner join partners p ON d.partnerid = p.partnerid
     WHERE d.doctypeid = 200
     ORDER BY d.date DESC
```

the error is in subquery, where i try to return the value of currencyRate at the date of facture. I need to return only a number, not all column

Comment: thanks diiN. here is the issue : THEN d.CurrencyNetValue/(select top 1(c.CurrencyRate) from CurrencyRates c inner join documents d on d.date=c.date where c.CurrencyId=2). I know top 1 is not correct, but need to return only a value ...

Comment: In your `currencyrates` table, would you have multiple entries on the same date? If not, there is no reason you would need a `top` function in your subquery if you join on the `d.date` from the outer query: `select c.CurrencyRate from CurrencyRates c where c.date=d.date and c.CurrencyId=2`

Comment: no, I have only a entry for every day. I have 4 currencies (USD, EUR, GBR, RON) for every day, but I have the condition currencyid = 2 (only EUR). Each line in currencyrates register a value. a row for EUR, a row for GBR, a row for USD.. I need only the row for EUR, but this query return me all values of EURO. I need only for the specific date which

Comment: did you try writing your subquery as I did in my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

Needed to add an inner join for a new "table"

inner join (select * from CurrencyRates where CurrencyId = 2) as cr on d.Date = cr.Date